# $Q$-values for Beta-decay

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I was reading up about $Q$-values for beta decay and apparently the $Q$-values for beta decay from a parent nucleus determines the maximum excitation energy allowed in the daughter nucleus.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually *not* the case.

Here's a counter-example, with all these decay graphs taken from the very nice "Firestone" Table of Isotopes:

[image: 20F beta decay]

$^{20}$F beta-decays into $^{20}$Ne with a Q-value of about 7MeV, i.e. the energy difference between these two isotopes' ground state is 7MeV. The decay can rarely go in the ground state, but most often fills an excited state at 1.6MeV. Obviously you can't decay into an excited state that has more energy than the Q-value by definition, but I don't think that's what you're asking about.

Now, we can look around those isotopes a bit:

[image: isotopes decaying into 20N]

As you can see, $^{20}$Ne can also be created in the electron capture decay of $^{20}$Na:

[image: 20na electron capture decay]

That has a Q-value of whopping 14MeV. The point is that it can fill a large number of excited states of the $^{20}$Ne daughter with energies of more than 7MeV above the $^{20}$Ne ground state. In this particular example, some of these can also alpha-decay $^{16}$O, but that doesn't change the fact that there can be excited states of a daughter isotope with an energy larger than the Q-value of parent decay.